# ModalDailog resizing

Tags: javascript

I changed the features of ModalDialog as

```
features = "scroll: no;\
            status: yes;\
            help: no;\
            center: yes;\
            dialogWidth: 1032px;\
            dialogHeight: 750px;\
            resizable: yes;"
```

But dialogwidth and dialog height is effected only for under desktop dispaly size.
If desktop dispaly size is 1024 x 768 , modal dialog can't resize over

```
"dialogWidth : 1024px; dialogHeight : 737px;"
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get screen.availHeight - (your browser header's height contains location bar and tabs) as maximum height and screen.availWidth - (default scroller's width)

In my PC, i can get 1905 X 1004, where my MAC's original resolution is 1920 X 1054

Width 15 is gone for scroller's width and height 50 is gone for location bar and tab's height

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I used screen.availHeight.But this showed dialog with so small size.How can I do?

Comment: use like this

showModalDialog("#","","dialogWidth:"+screen.availWidth+";dialogHeight:"+screen.availHeight)

Comment: I want to more dialog height over screen height.

Comment: You can't get that, you can't open any popup window like showModelDialog or window.open more than screen.availHeight and screen.availWidth